# How do I access an image from a list of items?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a mixed list of text and images and I would like to place the applicable text and image together on one card. The current code works for text however, when I try to add the image I always get an error. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

```
class Episode {
  String seasonEpisode;
  String airDate;
  Image epImage;

  Episode({this.seasonEpisode, this.airDate, this.epImage});
}
```

```
class EpisodeList extends StatefulWidget {

  /*final Episode episodes;*/

  @override
  _EpisodeListState createState() => _EpisodeListState();
}

class _EpisodeListState extends State<EpisodeList> {
  List<Episode> episodes = [
    Episode(seasonEpisode: 'S24:E1', airDate: 'February 18, 2020', epImage: Image.asset('assets/Bachelor1.jpeg')),
    Episode(seasonEpisode: 'S24:E2', airDate: 'February 25, 2020', epImage: Image.asset('assets/Bachelor1.jpeg')),
    Episode(seasonEpisode: 'S24:E3', airDate: 'February 31, 2020', epImage: Image.asset('assets/Bachelor1.jpeg')),
  ];

  Widget epCardTemplate(episode) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(episode.epImage),
          Text(
            episode.seasonEpisode
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 6.0),
          Text(
            episode.airDate
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: DARK_GREY_COLOR,
      body: Column(
        children: episodes.map((episode) => epCardTemplate(episode)).toList(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing in your code is equivalent to

```
children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(Image.asset('assets/......')),
          Text(
            episode.seasonEpisode
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 6.0),
          Text(
            episode.airDate
          ),
        ],
```

Basically, you are putting an image inside another image widget.